# RSA Decrypt with some letters of private key unknown

Tags: encryption, rsa, private-key

I have (e, n) = (1d35,c4b361851de35f080d3ca7352cbf372d) and ciphertext = a02d51d0e87efe1de
fc19f3ee899c31d, but my private key has 5 letters unknown like this 53a0a95b089cf23adb5
cc73f07XXXXX(X represents unknown).How can I test through all valid and possible private keys to find meaningful plaintext? Thanks for your help.

I have tried using 5 for-loop to generate all private keys, but having errors because it is not a valid private key. I'm not sure about the reason.

Comment: You can determine the full key by trying all possible values for the unknown parts, as you probably tried with the loops. To find the bug in your implementation you have to share your code. Because of your small key size of 128 bits you can alternatively factorize the modulus. E.g. [this site](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) does this in a fraction of a second. After finding p and q, you can analytically determine the private key and perform the decryption, which gives: _Q-system 1_.

Comment: You don't need 5 for loops, you can use just one: `for d in range(0x53a0a95b089cf23adb5cc73f0700000, 0x53a0a95b089cf23adb5cc73f0800000):` in python for example

Comment: Thanks for your help! Because I am not familiar with the Integer type in cryptopp, actually one for-loop is enough. I originally thought that the Integer type cannot do addition on it LOL.

Comment: Sorry for not posting any code. Actually I am using cpp for implementation. By the way, my friend ran the same program in terminal using macOS and finished in just few seconds but it took about 6 minutes for me to run in VS in windows 10. What causes the difference?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.